# multi part indentifier could not be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to use two tables in a stored procedure but am getting this error on the final line 
*''multi part identifier T.HireDate could not be bound''*

I'm guessing its to do with the joining of the tables but am a little lost. Heres my code:

```
CREATE PROC spPayIncreaseCheck
AS
SELECT T.ID,FName,LName,HireDate,Payrate
FROM Assignment.dbo.Payments pay
join Assignment.dbo.Teachers  T
ON pay.ID = T.ID
UPDATE Assignment.dbo.Payments
SET Payrate = 'High'
where T.HireDate < dateadd(year, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: The alias `T` is not present in your update, it's present in your select.  What are you trying to do with your stored proc?

Comment: I've tried using `Assignment.dbo.Teachers.HireDate`but get the same error regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to `update`, or are you trying to `select`?

That is the wrong form for an `update` using a join in sql server.

The correct form would be like so:

```
update pay
set Payrate = 'High'
from Assignment.dbo.Payments pay
  inner join Assignment.dbo.Teachers T
    on pay.ID = T.ID
where T.HireDate < dateadd(year, -3, getdate());
```

Also, are you sure `on pay.ID = T.ID` is the correct join clause? Normally you would expect to see something like `on pay.TeacherID = T.ID` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it. :)

Comment: @GerMc are you sure `on pay.ID = T.ID` is the correct join clause? Normally you would expect to see something like `on pay.TeacherID = T.ID` instead.

Comment: yes, the pay table is for Teachers only so the pay.ID refers to  ID on Teacher table. I guess my naming conventions aren't the best !

Comment: @GerMc Just making sure, wouldn't want you to update the wrong rows on accident.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the Assignment.dbo.Payments table and in the WHERE condition you have a t.HireDate but t is not an alias that is used in the UPDATE statement.
In UPDATE you cannot use aliases.

Also, please notice that the SELECT and UPDATE statements are completely non-related inside your stored procedure. It is not clear though if you need them to be related.

You need an UPDATE FROM to do a set-based update:

```
UPDATE Assignment.dbo.Payments
SET  Payrate = 'High'
FROM  
SELECT T.ID,FName,LName,HireDate,Payrate
FROM Assignment.dbo.Payments pay
JOIN Assignment.dbo.Teachers  T ON pay.ID = T.ID
WHERE T.HireDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: oh yes, I want them to be related.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this, is using an [exists clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) to check if the payment record matches the teacher record:

```
    update  Assignment.dbo.Payments
    set     Payrate = 'High'
    where   exists ( select 1
                     from   Assignment.dbo.Teachers
                     where  Payments.ID = Teachers.ID
                            and Teachers.HireDate < dateadd(year, -3, getdate()) )
```